# How to suppress pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user

Tags: git, pam, sshd

I have a Ubuntu (14.x) host serving as a Git repository box (via GitLab CE). Around 50 users are using shared user (in this case `gitlab`) to connect to the box to sync their repositories. This method works quite fine but unluckily it totally nukes my `/var/log/auth.log` which easily grows to 10 gigs per day with lines like this:

```
Apr 22 14:10:25 gitlab sshd[7434]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user git by (uid=227)
Apr 22 14:10:25 gitlab sshd[7435]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user gitlab
```

Is there a method to suppress this messages for this user and stop flooding my logfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure `rsyslogd` to discard messages mentioning the `gitlab` user. Create a file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` (say, `10-filter-git.conf`), containing:

```
if $syslogfacility-text startswith 'auth' and $msg contains 'gitlab' and  not ($msg contains 'failure') then ~
```

This is an [expression-based filter](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/filters.html#expression-based-filters) that:

- matches messages coming from facilities whose name begin with `auth`. Typically, the entries in `auth.log` are from the `auth` and `authpriv` facilities.
- matches messages containing `gitlab` - use your username here.
- matches messages not containing `failure` - I assume you'd still want to keep an eye out for authentication failures.
- `~` discards messages sent to it.

Then restart `rsyslogd`:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Now normal messages about the `gitlab` user shouldn't appear in `auth.log`.